# Replacing text with an image with a Monotouch.Dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I have a specific need to do what I'm about to describe, but I've never seen it done so don't know if it can be!

I have a settings dialog in my app created with Monotouch.Dialog. If an option isn't set, it displays "Not Set" in the placeholder. Normally when an option is set, the place holder is changed to reflect the change in option. However, what I would like it to do is change the placeholder with a UIImage to indicate it has been set.

I've looked around to see if this is possible, but haven't found much.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build your own custom Element that does that.

Check my blog for patterns on how to do this as a starting point:

http://tirania.org/monomac/archive/2011/Jan-18.html